# Java Homework - File Encryption

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, encryption, mapping

String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
String enc = "kngcadsxbvfhjtiumylzqropwe";

Hello, for my homework assignment I have to write a program that encodes or decodes a File, and then encodes or decodes the File using the mapping above. So for example, every 'a' becomes a 'k' when encoding a text, and every 'k' becomes an 'a' when decoding. Same concept if it is capital, and numbers and other characters are not encoded and remain the same.

Now the problem I am having is how to get the index of each character from the file and then correspond it to the index of the encrypt array. As you can see, I was using a switch statement but that is just going to take forever and I know there has to be something in the api that can help me with this I just can't find anything. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Encode {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
         char[] alphabet = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
         char[] decryption = {'k','n','g','c','a','d','s','x','b','v','f','h','j','t','i','u','m','y','l','z','q','r','o','p','w','e'};
         char[] alphabetLower = new char [26];
         char[] alphabetUpper = new char[26];
         char[] decryptedPassword = new char[26];
    /*   for(int i=0; i<decryptedPassword.length; i++)
         {
             decryptedPassword[i] = '';
         }*/



            //add the letters of the alphabet to alphabet lower
            for(int i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
            {
                alphabetLower[i] = alphabet[i];
            }
            //add the letters of the alphabet to alphabetdecryptedPassword
            for(int i=0; i<alphabet.length; i++)
            {
                alphabetUpper[i] = Character.toUpperCase(alphabet[i]);
            }


        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input file name



        String filePath = "C:/Users/omid/Desktop/";
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name for which you want to decode");
        String fileName = "password"; //input.nextLine();
        String file = filePath + fileName + ".txt";
        System.out.println("File name entered: " + file);

        //import file

        File fileEncrypted = new File(file);

        Scanner in = new Scanner(fileEncrypted);
        String document = "";

        //store entire password in document

        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            document = in.nextLine();
        }
        in.close();

            System.out.println("password normal: " + document);
            char[] letters = new char[document.length()];

        for(int i = 0; i<document.length(); i++)
        {
                letters[i] = document.charAt(i);
        }

        for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(letters[i]);
        }


/*

    for(int i=0; i<letters.length; i++)
        {
            switch(letters[i])
            {
             case 'a':
                decryptedPassword[0] = decryption[0];
                     break;
                 case 'A':
                decryptedPassword[0] = decryption[0];
                     break;
                 case 'b':
                decryptedPassword[1] = decryption[1];
                     break;
                case 'B':
                    decryptedPassword[1] = decryption[1];
                     break;
                 case 'c':
                    decryptedPassword[2] = decryption[2];
                     break;
                case 'C':
                     decryptedPassword[2] = decryption[2];
                     break;
                 case 'd':
                    decryptedPassword[3] = decryption[3];
                     break;
                 case 'D':
                     decryptedPassword[3] = decryption[4];
                     break;
                 case 'e':
                    decryptedPassword[4] += 1;
                     break;
                 case 'E':
                     decryptedPassword[4] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'f':
                    decryptedPassword[5] += 1;
                     break;
                 case 'F':
                     decryptedPassword[5] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'g':
                     decryptedPassword[6] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'G':
                     decryptedPassword[6] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'h':
                     decryptedPassword[7] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'H':
                     decryptedPassword[7] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'i': 
                     decryptedPassword[8] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'I':
                     decryptedPassword[8] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'j':
                     decryptedPassword[9] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'J':
                     decryptedPassword[9] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'k':
                     decryptedPassword[10] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'K':
                     decryptedPassword[10] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'l':
                     decryptedPassword[11] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'L':
                     decryptedPassword[11] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'm': 
                     decryptedPassword[12] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'M':
                     decryptedPassword[12] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'n':
                     decryptedPassword[13] += 1;
                     break;
                 case 'N':
                     decryptedPassword[13] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'o':
                     decryptedPassword[14] +=1;
                    break;
                 case 'O':
                     decryptedPassword[14] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'p':
                     decryptedPassword[15] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'P':
                     decryptedPassword[15] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'q':
                     decryptedPassword[16] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'Q':
                     decryptedPassword[16] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'r':
                     decryptedPassword[17] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'R':
                     decryptedPassword[17] +=1;
                     break;
                 case's':
                     decryptedPassword[18] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'S':
                     decryptedPassword[18] +=1;
                     break;
                 case't':
                     decryptedPassword[19] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'T':
                     decryptedPassword[19] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'u':
                     decryptedPassword[20] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'U':
                     decryptedPassword[20] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'v':
                     decryptedPassword[21] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'V':
                     decryptedPassword[21] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'w':
                     decryptedPassword[22] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'W':
                     decryptedPassword[22] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'x':
                     decryptedPassword[23] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'X':
                     decryptedPassword[23] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'y':
                     decryptedPassword[24] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'Y':
                     decryptedPassword[24] +=1;
                     break;
                 case'z':
                     decryptedPassword[26] +=1;
                     break;
                 case 'Z':
                     decryptedPassword[26] +=1;
                     break;
            }

        }

    */

/*for(int i=0; i<decryptedPassword.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println("password decrypted: " + decryptedPassword);
}*/








    }

    private static String split(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: You can use a `HashMap` for this. Add all the alphabets as `Key`s and their mappings as `Value`s. While encrypting, you have to search the `HashMap` for the alphabet `Key` to get its mapping `Value`. While decrypting, you have to search the `HashMap` for the mapping `Value` to get its alphabet `Key`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using a hash structure. Essentially each character maps in a 1 to 1 mapping to every other character, so that fits nicely into a hashtable or hashmap structure. Rather than using a switch statement, just look up the character in the map.

```
HashMap<Character, Character> encryptionMap = new HashMap<Character,Character>();

for (char c : alphabet) {
    for (char d: decryption) {
        encryptionMap.put(c,d);
    }
}
....
char nextChar = "a";
char encryptedChar = encryptionMap.get(nextChar);
```

You'll need an encryptionMap and a decryptionMap in the other direction (decryption > alphabet).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider reading your file using BufferedReader but that's a different problem. As far as encoding a character without using switch, consider that a character is encoded internally as an integer. You can Google "Ascii Table" to see how each character is encoded. For example, 'A' is encoded as 65 and 'a' is encoded as 97. You can use this to your advantage to index into your alphabet and decryption arrays. If your character is uppercase, we subtract 65 from it to get the index of that character in the array. So 'A' becomes 0, 'B' becomes 1, etc. Similarly if the letter is lowercase, we subtract 97 from it.

For example lets assume that ch contains the letter you want to decode:

```
int index = -1;
//ch is between A and Z
if (ch >= 65 && ch <= 90){
    index = ch - 65;
} else if (ch >= 97 &7 ch <= 122){//ch is between a and z
    index = ch - 97;
}

if (index > -1){
    char encodedChar = decryption[index];
}
```